# Updating multiple pandas columns using one custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I need to clean up quite a few columns in a pandas dataframe; so I defined and used multiple functions via the apply method on dataframe columns.

A dummy example:

```
def fn_a(x):
    if x<50:
        return 'OK'
    else:
        return 'not OK'

def fn_b(x):
    if x<=40:
        return 'too small'
    elif x>40 and x<70:
        return 'just right'
    else:
        return 'too high'
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 2)), columns=['a','b'])
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(fn_a)
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(fn_b)
```

Is there a way to apply only one function, i.e. define a single `fn()` function and pass that into the apply method instead going column by column? In other words, what should I put in `fn` such that

```
def fn(x):
    ...

df = df.apply(fn)
```

suffices?

Comment: You better use vectorization for performance....

Comment: But your two functions are different, how can you programmatically code this into a single function? Or you want to unify both `fn_a` and `fn_b` into a single function with an if statement?

Comment: For the function in the example, you should _not_ use `apply` at all. Is the example close enough to your real functions?

Comment: @DYZ They are similar in spirit; basically combining a bunch of different values under certain number of umbrella terms. Should I use `np.where` here? Why not `apply`?

Comment: @itaishz yes, my question is about combining multiple if-else statements (that are specific to particular columns) under a single function and apply it for the entire dataframe.

Comment: For the first function, you would write `df['a']=np.where(df['a']<50,'OK','not OK')`. That's the Pandas way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reproducible data:**

```py
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 2)), columns=['a','b'])
```

```
    a   b
0  44  47
1  64  67
2  67   9
3  83  21
4  36  87
```

---

**Using pandas apply:**

If you really wanna use apply for this, you can set `axis=1` and retrieve the column name with `x[colname]` where `x` is your current row:

```
def fn_a(x):
    x['a'] = 'OK' if x['a'] < 50 else 'not OK'
    if x['b'] <= 40:
        x['b'] = 'too small'
    elif x['b'] > 40 and x['b'] < 70:
        x['b'] = 'just right'
    else:
        x['b'] = 'too high'
    return x

df = df.apply(fn_a, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        a           b
0      OK  just right
1  not OK  just right
2  not OK   too small
3  not OK   too small
4      OK    too high
```

---

**Using a vectorized approach**:

You may consider using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). Also, take a look at [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html). You can set a function do update the dataframe *inplace* with:

```py
def fn(df):
    df['a'] = np.where(df.a.lt(50), 'OK', 'not OK')
    df['b'] = np.select(
        condlist=[df.b.le(40), df.b.gt(40) & df.b.lt(70)],
        choicelist=['too small', 'just right'],
        default='too high'
    )
    
fn(df)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
        a           b
0      OK  just right
1  not OK  just right
2  not OK   too small
3  not OK   too small
4      OK    too high
```

If do not want to modify the dataframe *inplace*, make a copy inside the function, modify the copied dataframe, then return it:

```py
def fn(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['a'] = np.where(df.a.lt(50), 'OK', 'not OK')
    df['b'] = np.select(
        condlist=[df.b.le(40), df.b.gt(40) & df.b.lt(70)],
        choicelist=['too small', 'just right'],
        default='too high'
    )
    return df

df = fn(df)
print(df)
```

which returns the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def fn(x1, x2):
    return [fn_a(x1), fn_b(x2)]

df[['c', 'd']] = df.apply(lambda row: fn(row.a, row.b), axis=1).values.tolist()
```